# What's a good standalone viewer/renderer for RS reports?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Not that technical a question I guess, but what do you guys use? I normally use CRM, but I have a use for a totally standalone one, and I'm not sure what to use for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Have a look at the Microsoft Report Viewer control.